# Were any animals hurt during shooting of the 2020 movie "Rogue"?

Tags: plot-explanation, rogue-2020

The Megan Fox movie Rogue opens with some caged lions scene, the lions are being irritated by beating on the cages. One lions is brutally hurt. Then the lion attacks people.

My question is were any lions hurt or abused (physically or mentally) during the shooting of those scenes?

If no, then how were those scenes shot?

If yes, then why was it allowed and why the film was not banned?

Comment: It seems clear from a few seconds searching that the animals were probably CGI but lions have been trained in Hollywood for decades to "act".

Answer (score 0):

No lions were hurt. A quick Google search will show you that M. J. Bassett, the writer, director, and producer, is a major animal rights advocate. The entire movie is a "don't mess with lions" film. The scenes were shot using CGI lions, which is very easy to see from the quality of the effects.

Answer (score 0):

According to the film's credits,  the animals used in filming were monitored by the "*[Animal Anti-Cruelty League](https://www.aacl.co.za/)*"

[image]

I think we can reasonably assume that no animals were *intentionally* harmed, or this organisation would not allow their logo and brand to be used.

Comment: I've reached out to the individual from the AACL who worked on set (Rulof Jackson) to see if he knows whether any animals were **un**intentionally harmed during filming.